# White screen issue in electron

Tags: angular, electron

I have an angular application that is converted to electron. On building the application, white screen comes but on reloading, the application runs perfectly. What can be the cause for it ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my snippet of main.js file  :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, session, ipcMain, globalShortcut, Menu, dialog, screen } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const Path = require('path');
process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = 'true';

let mainWindow
let appicon = `${__dirname}/dist/sbox-signage/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png`;

let signage_storage = app.getPath('userData') + '/signage_storage/';
let playlistUrl = ""; //any URL

function createWindow() {

    // Check if Windows OS    
    let isWin = process.platform === "win32";
    global.signage_storage = signage_storage;

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        frame: isWin,
        kiosk: !isWin,
        icon: appicon,
        show: false,
        resizable: true,
        fullscreen: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webSecurity: false,
            enableWebSQL: false,
            spellcheck: false,
            paintWhenInitiallyHidden: false,
            devTools: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })

    // mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/sbox-signage/SplashScreen.html`);
    // setTimeout(function () {
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/sbox-signage/index.html`);
    // }, 1000);

    //**mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/sbox-signage/index.html`);

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow.destroy();
    })

    // Electron Menu
    if (isWin) {
        //let getmenu0 = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menu.template)
        let getmenu = null;
        Menu.setApplicationMenu(getmenu);
        mainWindow.maximize();
    }

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', function () {
        // First time load issue fixed        
        //**mainWindow.reload();
        mainWindow.show();
        //setTimeout(mainWindow.show(), 21000);
        // For API Cors-Origin first time block issue fix
        app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-features", "OutOfBlinkCors");
    })

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        mainWindow.focus();
    });
}
} //the scopes are not properly closed. (can  ignore)
```

here's my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sbox Signage</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of the white screen somehow by changing the directory path and changing the interval of splash screen in electron. It is not a permanent fix but will suffice :

In the main.js:

```
window.loadURL(
url.format({
pathname: path.join(__dirname,'/dist/index.html'), //app name removed
protocol:'file:,
slashes:true,
})
);

mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/SplashScreen.html`);
 setTimeout(function () {
 mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
    }, 5000);
```

In angular.json

Set `Projects->architect->build->options->outputPath to "dist" only.`

In tsconfig.json :

Set `compilerOptions to "es5".`